# Upgrade of 12.04.4 LTS to 14.04 LTS fails on Pandaboard

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 14.04

I'm trying to upgrade 12.04.4 LTS to 14.04 LTS on a Pandaboard. The upgrade via `do-release-upgrade -d`fails with

```
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg                        
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg                         
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg                       
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                     
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release                            
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release                             
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release                           
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      

Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

W:Failed to fetch 
http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/Release Unable to 
find expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages' in Release file 
(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file) 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/Release 
Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages' in Release 
file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file) 
, W:Failed to fetch
.... 
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or 
old ones used instead.
```

Hitting http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/trusty/ in the browser I can see that armel is indeed missing. So I'm wondering how I can upgrade from 12.04.4 to 14.04 on that board.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Ubuntu has dropped support for armel after 12.04

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-November/036106.html

You could try switch to armhf

https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/is_it_armhf_or_armel